# Remove last character from a file in unix

Tags: unix, awk, sed

Have

```
08-01-12|07-30-13|08-09-32|12-43-56|
```

Want

```
08-01-12|07-30-13|08-09-32|12-43-56
```

I want to remove just the last `|`.

Comment: Show 2 lines of input and associated output as it's not 100% clear if you really mean the last character from the file or the last character from each line in the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

quick and dirty

```
sed 's/.$//' YourFile
```

a bit secure

```
sed 's/[|]$//' YourFile
```

allowing space

```
sed 's/[|][[:space:]]*$//' YourFile
```

same for only last char of last line (thansk @amelie for this comment) :
add a `$`in front so on quick and dirty it gives `sed '$ s/.$//' YourFile`

Comment: ++ ... or extremely dirty `perl -lpe 'chop' file`.

Comment: this does remove a character from every line of file

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged with `awk`, find here two approaches, one for every interpretation of your question:

- If you want to remove `|` if it is the last character:

  ```
  awk '{sub(/\|$/,"")}1' file
  ```

Equivalent to `sed s'/|$//' file`, only that escaping `|` because it has a special meaning in regex content ("or").

- If you want to remove the last character, no matter what it is:

  ```
  awk '{sub(/.$/,"")}1' file
  ```

Equivalent to `sed s'/.$//' file`, since `.` matches any character.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
08-01-12|07-30-13|08-09-32|12-43-56|
rrr.
$ awk '{sub(/\|$/,"")}1' a
08-01-12|07-30-13|08-09-32|12-43-56
rrr.                                 # . is kept
$ awk '{sub(/.$/,"")}1' a
08-01-12|07-30-13|08-09-32|12-43-56
rrr                                  # . is also removed
```